# Specifying routes by subdomain in Express using vhost middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, subdomain, middleware

I'm using the `vhost` express/connect middleware and I'm a bit confused as to how it should be used. I want to have one set of routes apply to hosts with subdomains, and another set to apply for hosts without subdomains.

In my app.js file, I have

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.use...(middlware)...
app.use(express.vhost('*.host', require('./domain_routing')("yes")));
app.use(express.vhost('host', require('./domain_routing')("no")));
app.use...(middlware)...

app.listen(8000);
```

and then in `domain_routing.js`:

```
module.exports = function(subdomain){

  var app = express.createServer();

  require('./routes')(app, subdomain);

  return app;
}
```

and then in `routes.js` I plan to run sets of routes, dependent on whether the subdomain variable passed in is `"yes"` or `"no"`.

Am I on the right track or is this not how you use this middleware? I'm a bit confused on the fact that there are two `app` server instances being created (as that's how examples on the web seem to do things). Should I instead pass in the original `app` server instance and just use that instead of creating a separate one instead the subdomain router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. You **should** have a different server instance for each of the vhost. Be it a `http.Server` or `express app`.

If you pass the original `app`, a request you sent to the vhost will be emitted to the original app. So, unless the vhost has paths which are not used in original server, it will get response as if the request was sent to original server.

From the connect docs

```
connect()
  .use(connect.vhost('foo.com', fooApp))
  .use(connect.vhost('bar.com', barApp))
  .use(connect.vhost('*.com', mainApp))
```

Comment: Thanks! And my other question is that if I specify middleware to be used for the original server instance, and then I use separate server instances for the vhosts, will the middleware used for the original server be carried over to the vhost? Or should I instead be using middleware exclusively on the vhosts (except for the vhost middleware on the original server) Basically, I'm looking for a seamless way to use middleware on all possible vhosts, rather than having to explicity use the same middleware on each one of the vhosts which is kind of repetitive...

Comment: No, you need not use middleware exclusively on all vhosts. Any middleware you want to use for all the apps can be `.use`'d before a vhost is `.use`'d

Comment: That's great! But out of curiosity, how does that work? I guess I'm a bit confused as to what `server.emit("request", req, res);` does behind the scenes.

Comment: Applying middlewares will modify the `req` and `res` objects and it is done synchronously. So, when a `req` is emitted, middlewares get applied until it reaches `vhost` middleware, there vhost will not allow it to go to the next middleware in the main app.

Comment: Ok, but i can still call `app.listen()` on the main app after using the `vhost` middleware, right?

Comment: Yes, it will listen to requests as long as vhost doesn't block them

Comment: It seems that calling `app.set('views', paths.viewsPath); app.set('view engine', 'jade');` on the original server before using the `vhost` middleware didn't work but calling it on the `vhost` server did. Why is this?

Comment: `app.set` is a config for `app`, so, you need to define it for all apps. Read my earlier comment, all `app.use` before `app.use(vhost)` need not be duplicated. I wasn't talking about `app.set`.